# How to run MySQL delete query on specific time interval?

Tags: mysql

How can I run a mysql query

```
Delete from `wp_post`.`news` where PostID=0
```

every 5 minutes on the server.

I am hoping for options using either MySQL workbench or Windows Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create **Scheduled event in MySQL**. Below query delete data from `wp_post` table on every 5 minutes & stops executing query after `1 hour`.

```
CREATE EVENT myEventName
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
  Delete from 'wp_post'.'news' where PostID=0;
```

**For more info on MySQL Events :** [MySQL Events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

**Example of Recurring & Non-recurring events in MySQL :** [Working with MySQL Scheduled Event](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

Comment: This event is only executed once and thus does not fulfill the questioners needs.

Comment: @GhostGambler We can create scheduled events in MySQL. I have updated my answer. I think `ENDS` is optional. Am I correct regarding `ENDS` ?

Comment: `starts` and `ends` is optional, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a cron job for that. Create a shell or php script and set it to run every 5 minutes